# Correct Regex to Prevent Java Scanner From Returning a Zero Length String

Tags: java, regex, newline, java.util.scanner, string

I am trying to read in the individual numbers from a file with multiple lines of numbers separated by commas.  The java code I am doing this with is:

```
try {
        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(unsolvedBoardLocation));
        Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile("[,\\r\\n]");
        System.out.println(myPattern.pattern());
        fileScanner.useDelimiter(myPattern);

        while(fileScanner.hasNext()) {
            int i = fileScanner.nextInt();
            System.out.print(i);

        }
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SudokuBoard.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

The contents of the file I am reading has no whitespaces and is as follows:

```
8,0,0,9,3,0,0,0,2
0,0,9,0,0,0,0,4,0
```

Since I created the text file in Windows I know that there is a \r\n following the 2.  In my original version of the program the Scanner was returning 2\r\n, so I added the \r\n to the delimiter to try and prevent this, but I am still having problems.  I am getting an InputMissmatchException.  The full stack trace is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
at my.puzzle.sudoku.SudokuBoard.<init>(SudokuBoard.java:31)
at my.puzzle.sudoku.Sudoku.main(Sudoku.java:8)
    Java Result: 1
```

I think the reason I am getting this exception is because the Scanner is returning "" after the end of the 2.  This is not what nextInt() is expecting, thus throwing the error.  I am trying to prevent this but I am not sure how to do this with just regex. Since I am generating the input file I could simply format it with whitespaces and get it to work.  I could also read each token in as a string and check if the string can be read as a valid number and move to the next token if not; however, for my own learning purposes I would like to know how it could be done with regex only.  I am have already read the java tutorial on regex, but I have never used regex before and am having a hard time.

To be clear my question is "how do I prevent regex from returning a string of zero length in this scenario."

Any help I could get would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a guess, but is the scanner seeing the `\r` as a delimiter, then a zero-length string before it recognizes `\n` as the next delimiter?

If that's the case, can you use `[,\\r\\n]+` as your pattern?

Comment: Try with `[,\\r\\n]+` pattern.

Comment: Wow, that did it.  I tried it with [,\\r\\n+] and various variations on that, but did not add it outside the regex class.  That was so simple I feel kind of stupid.  Thanks so much!!

Comment: Enclosing characters in square-brackets is regex for "any one of these characters."  Adding the `+` means "one or more of the preceding item."  So the `+` needs to be outside the brackets in order for the expression to be interpreted as "one or more commas, CRs, or LFs."

Answer (score 0):

Either end the regex with `$` or try `\d`.